How to share artifacts between workflows in GitHub Actions?
workflowA generates artifacts which are needed to be consumed by workflowB.
Both workflows are triggered manually with workflow_dispatch, and I prefer not to use workflow_call or workflow_run events (as I do not want that workflowB will be triggered immediately once workflowA finishes).
For artifacts download I'm using actions/download-artifact@v4.
In order to reference the artifacts generated by workflowA I need the run-id, see download-artifact docs.
I would like that workflowB to pick up the run-id automatically, rather than manually entered it if defined as inputs to workflowB.
Is there a way in GitHub Actions to support that?
For example, is there a way to share outputs and/or environment variables (env) across workflows?
Any creative solutions would be much appreciated !

Option 1. Using workflow_run trigger. This is the easiest option as you can find the run id of the triggering workflow from
github.event.workflow_run.id

However, you did not want to trigger this workflow immediately. If you still wanted to benefit from this simplicity, you could associate the 2nd workflow with an environment that requires manual approval.
Option 2. Use GitHub API to get all recent runs. Filter them by workflow name. The first found entry is the one you want. You will need to use the same PAT you will use to download the artifacts. You will need to generate it with required permissions and store it in the repository secrets.
You could use GitHub CLI, installed by default on GitHub hosted runners to make API calls easier:
GH_TOKEN=${{ secrets.PAT }} 
gh api /repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/actions/runs | jq -r ‘.[] | select(.name == “Workflow 1”) | .[0].id’


Referring to option-1 - why not using context.payload.workflow_run.id instead?
Referring to option-2 - if both workflows are in the same repository, then wouldn't it be better to use github.token context?

@Nir, regarding Option 1 - Isn't context.payload.workflow_run.id only available when using GitHub script?  I suspect that when using yaml syntax, we can only use existing context names individually. Worth checking here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts.

@Nir, regarding Option 2, I believe that default github.token or GITHUB_TOKEN is only scoped to pull artifacts stored against current workflow, while PAT is scoped to a repo and can pull artifacts stored against any workflow from this repo

I'm not going to describe sharing across workflows, but I will describe jobs:
actions/upload-artifact outputs the id, so you want to id: somethingUnique your upload, then your first & second jobs will:
jobs:
  first:
    outputs:
      uniqueThing: ${{ steps.somethingUnique.outputs.artifact-id }}
    steps:
      - id: somethingUnique
// impl. skipped

  second:
    needs: [first]
    name: Do things to ${{ needs.first.outputs.uniqueThing }}

"But wait, I told you I wanted a delay between them!"
Yep! And that's not happening yet, but all you need to do is head on over to the Environments configuration tab at https://github.com/YOUR-SCOPE/YOUR-REPO/settings/environments and create one, perhaps called "manual-approval", and then configure it with a "Required reviewers" setting.
Now, you just environment: manual-approval your second job and it'll wait for you to kick it off!
Where this might not solve for your use case is that it means there's only one workflow_dispatch, so you'll need to provide any inputs up front, rather than having two different workflows that you dispatch.
